# When scrollviewer becomes visible other controls move to different position

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, scrollviewer

I’ve got a listbox which has vertical scrollviewer set to auto, so when user adds more items than can be visible on the screen, then the scrollbar appears. The problem is that when it appears, it moves other things, like the add button which is placed next to listbox. Is there any way to have it hidden (so it has the space for it), but then make it visible when needed?

I just don’t want all that stuff around to jump, anytime scrollviewer becomes visible or hidden.

Regards
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you donot set the width of your ListBox or you set it to Auto(which is by default). Try setting it to some value like below code, you shouldn't face any issue.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" OverridesDefaultStyle="True">
        <ListBox Height="150" Width="125" x:Name="NamesListBox"
           ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
        <Button Height="30" Width="100" 
           Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"  Content="Add"/>
</StackPanel>

private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NamesListBox.Items.Add(DateTime.Now);
}
```